# Sharepoint 2010 new ApplicationPage LayoutsPageBase not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010

Hello I'm trying to develop an application with vs2012 in sharepoint sharepoint 2010 sandbox on but I have a problem with the packages template vs2012.

I created a new project sharepoint 2010 from standard templates vs 2012.
I inserted a new application page but the object from which it inherits (LayoutsPageBase) is not found.
In the References folder is present Microsoft.SharePoint but in the hierarchy of the library is not present the object LayoutsPageBase.

Help me please.

Tanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that using sandbox solutions there is no way of inheriting from LayoutsPageBase, as application pages are not supported in Sandbox Solutions.

Your one way of working around that is deploying your solution as a farm solution as opposed to the sandbox one. Also, you can try to use content pages instead of application pages. Here is a good blog post getting into detail of such approach:

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Custom-application-pages-in-the-SharePoint-2010-Sandbox.aspx